# Android Wear RemoteInput setChoices customization

Tags: android, wear-os

By following the "Add Pre-defined Text Responses" section in the following link, I was able to add the choices like "Yes", "No".

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/voice-input.html

I want to customize the Icon with respect to each choice. How to do that?

**Existing one:**

[image: Remote Input Choice action]

**What I want:**

In the below image i want to customize each icon.

[image]

Code Used.

```
RemoteInput remoteInput = new RemoteInput.Builder("com.example.android.support.wearable.notifications.REPLY")
                .setLabel("Choose Car")
                .setAllowFreeFormInput(true)
                .setChoices(new String[] { "Choice 1", "Choice 2", "Choice 3" })
                .build();

        NotificationCompat.Action chooseCarAction = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(
                R.drawable.uber_badge,
                "Choose Car",
                uberPendingIntent)
                .addRemoteInput(remoteInput)
                .build();

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{50, 50, 50})
                .setContentTitle("Wake Up")
                .setContentText("Train reached Bangalore Cantonment Station.")
                        //.setStyle(bigStyle.bigText(content))

                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher))
        mNotificationManager.notify(notifyId, notificationBuilder.build());
```